# Section heading and figure on same page (landscape)

Tags: landscape

first my example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,abstracton]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\section{Appendix}
%EXAMPLE #1
\subsection{Iteration 1 -- Prototyp}
\begin{landscape}
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{images/it2.pdf}
 \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\newpage

%EXAMPLE #2
\subsection{Iteration 2 -- Prototyp}
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
   \rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{images/it2.pdf}}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

the result: [image: latex output] 
the problem (EXAMPLE#1): page one shows the heading and page two shows the figure. i want to display both on the same page. how can i realize this without hundred lines of source code? 
the problem (EXAMPLE#2): blank page with additional confusing scaling. 
similar questions have already been asked, but there is no appropriate solution to solve the problem smart. almost there are questions regarding tables, not figures.
thanks for support :)

Comment: Hi and welcome, i think `landscape` will always clear a page before doing the stuff inside. Do you need a caption for that figure?

Comment: hi and thanks for your answer :) do you know any other solution to show both, the figure and the heding on the same page within a landscape format?

Comment: Do you need a caption for that figure? `\iftrue\else \rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{name}}`

Comment: unfortunately i need a caption. the example is only a snippet of the total appendix.

Comment: If the caption can be parallel to the section title, the solution is trivial. If it should be rotated as well, it's more complicated.

Comment: I've tried \rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{images/it2.pdf}}. thats an acceptable solution. but "width=1.0\linewidth" doesn't fit with the margins. the figure is smaller and if i change width to e.g. 1.2, latex make a pagebreak though there is enough space...

Comment: You have to be aware of a few things: i don't see your document, especially not your figure. I don't have any information on it's aspect ratio. I don't know if you used a figure environment. I don't know if you used a caption. Please edit your above minimal working example to avoid guesswork.

Comment: Hi Johannes_B, I hope the revised example describes the problem more comprehensive :)

Comment: Your *example#1* shows the expected and documented behaviour. In the second one, the figure is just too large and doesn't fit the text area. Load package `showframe` to confirm. Please be aware, that a figure-environment always adds some vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

The second example works if you select right dimension for picture size. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,abstracton]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
%    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{showframe}

    \begin{document}
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Iteration 2 -- Prototyp}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textheight]{example-image-b}}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Is this what you looking for?